# Fast copy of mysql database gets error

Tags: mysql, myisam, frm

I need to copy over a large mysql database with myisam tables. The fastest way for me to do it is by copying over the mysql/data directory. The .MYI and .MYD files copy over smoothly. However, copying the .frm file is causing mysql to show an error when I query the database. :

```
#1033 - Incorrect information in file: 'mytable.frm'
```

When I did the copy I stopped the mysql server. Also, I made sure that the owner and permissions are set correctly. The `repair table` command wouldn't work either because of the same aforementioned error. What am I doing wrong here?

(A possible solution would be to do a mysqldump of just the data structure which would be a fast process and then I would only need to copy over the .MYI and .MYD files. However, I would like to know what I am doing wrong with the copy before I go on a more complicated route)

## Update

Following up on @RickJames comments - Here is a more detailed explanation of what I am doing:

I'm using cp command on a Linux server to copy files from one db to another db on the same server. The version that I am using  `mysql  Ver 14.12 Distrib 5.0.77` did not work. Inspired by @RickJames comment, I  tried doing the same operation on a different server with `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.29` and it worked beautifully. That being said, I'm still intrigued as to why it doesn't work with the older version

Comment: What tool was used for the copy?  From what OS to what?

Comment: @RickJames I'm using cp command on a Linux server to copy files from one db to another db on the same server.

Comment: Hmmm...  Nothing _should_ have gone wrong with the `.frm` in an intra-server `cp`.  The `.frm`. is _rarely_ in an state that could lead to your symptom.  What version of MySQL in both cases?

Comment: @RickJames See update to question

Comment: I would expect cp in 5.0 to 5.0 to work.  I would worry about jumping 3 major versions (over 5.1 and 5.5) to get to 5.6.  There have been significant changes over that time.  Sorry, I am still stumped.

Comment: Did you check to see that the version of the source mysql database matches the target mysql database?